# How to set outer glow effect on click relative layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am working with a relative layout in Android. I want to have a glow effect when I click on a relative layout on screen. How to archive it?

Comment: which type of glow ? can you show some image or screen shot?

Comment: i have relative layout which has backgound color white.i like to have glow on border with different color e.g. blue when i click on relative layout. so that user can see that layout is clicked Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about Ripple Effect ?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have posted it seems you want your layout to have two different backgrounds depending on whether it has been clicked or not.

You achieve this by setting a selector to background

[selector example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/)

Comment: @Mitul Chauhan for that you have to make 9 patch image using GIMP or photo shop and have to set it in selector.as user2041902 mentioned.